# Not returning to parent activity when back pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities, A(the root activity) and B which is launched from A. Pressing back from B returns to A except 1 case. `If I am in B, go to home screen, launch the app again from recent apps, B comes to foreground but pressing back leads to home screen instead of A.` If I get back to the app by launching from icon and not from recent apps, shows me activity A, which, let's say, is correct(although B should be shown and pressing back from B should lead to A).

Acitivity A:

```
<activity android:name=".AudioRecTabsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <!--  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">-->
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Activity B:

```
<activity android:name=".settings.SettingsActivityOld"
            android:label="@string/settings_activity_title"/>
```

Launching act B from A:

```
intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivityOld.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: try removing singleInstance from manifest and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal if you are using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` since Activity B runs in a new Task and Activity A is the only Activity in its Task. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks)

Comment: You are right, changing singleInstance from activity A with singleTop solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [Activity#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) in activity B. It should remove the current activity from the activity stack and return you to the previous.

Comment: He is able to go back to Activity A from B when not from recent apps. So overriding does not come into picture.

Comment: I think Activity#finish() is already done by super.onbackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

Override backpress method of your B activity and start activity A from there

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```